# android - MediaPlayer stops working at some point

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have been working on an app, and it involves sound.
Now, I use this to start it:

```
final MediaPlayer tick = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tick_16);
tick.start();
```

But for some reason, after some time (depends on the device, on HTC One it is a few seconds and in others a few minuets) all sound stopps. 
What is the cause of it and how can I solve it?

Comment: do you get an error? can you put up the log if you do

Comment: @hello_world no error

Comment: Try to use the `setScreenOnWhilePlaying` or `setWakeMode` methods to prevent the device from going to sleep.

Comment: check if your activity is getting paused. put in a log statement in `onPause`

Comment: @Titus It happens when the device is not asleep

Comment: @hello_world everything is working apart from sound so it is not paused.

Comment: Can you put in some more code?

Comment: @hello_world, there is no much to it, the whole app is an onClickListener() that outputs a sound every click...

Comment: Run the app in debug mode and see if the state of the media player the second it stops playing. It might help you. There is nothing more that I can offer bud. You are on your own

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial to play audio :
**http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm**

you may be use tick.start(); in **onResume()** method of your activity class

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the `MediaPlayer` in a `Service` and a `Notification` inside `startForeground()`.

Comment: Check the Google docs.  Binding a `MediaPlayer` to a `Notification` inside a `Service` with `startForeground()` will keep the `MediaPlayer` in your `Service` going.